# LOAD DATA INFILE for Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I saw many posts to upload a `.xlsx` file to MySQL, to a permanent database table. I was wondering how I can do that in Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

I tried:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.Cal_table 
FROM 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\Cal.xlsx'
WITH (DATAFILETYPE = 'char', 
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' , --typically this is a comma or tab
      ROWTERMINATOR = 'slash n',  --or slash r if it's coming from unix/linix 
      FIRSTROW = 2 --assuming the first row had column names...if not firstrow=1
     )
```

However, the above does not work.

Comment: An xslx file is not a csv file. You better use SSIS to import the data.

Comment: Define *does not work* - do you get an error?? If so, ***please*** post this error here (since we cannot possibly read your screen, nor your mind). Does it insert no data at all? Does it insert *wrong* data?

Comment: Have you tried SQL Import Export Wizard?? That's the simplest way.

Comment: @ZoharPeled thank you for the help!

Comment: @sujith thank you!